# Grammatik und Bedeutung eines langen deutschen Satzes

Tags: grammar, meaning, meaning-in-context, grammaticality

Ich habe folgenden Satz verfasst. Ein Freund teilte mir mit, dass er ein wenig unverständlich sei.

> *Den Umstand, dass die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglied zwischen den Fachbereichen Kulturwissenschaft,
>   Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft
>   und Informatik und deren theoretischen Ansätze und empirischen
>   Methoden fungiert, finde ich höchst interessant und bewundernswert.*

Meine Fragen:

- Kann man diesen Satz so schreiben? Ist er grammatisch und
  orthographisch korrekt?
- Warum wirkt der Satz unter Umständen unverständlich?
- Ich möchte den Satz in einem Motivationsschreiben verwenden. Ist er
  in dieser Form passend?

Comment: Ausser, dass du nach dem langen Nebensatz nicht mehr wusstest, dass das Prädikat in diesem Nebensatz im Plural stehen muss  (*fungieren*, es sind immerhin zwei Subjekte), ist dass ein akzeptabler deutscher Satz.  Stilistisch würde man wahrscheinlich anmerken, dass die Klammer zwischen Subjekt und Prädikat zu weit aufgeht und früher geschlossen werden sollte, ist aber noch akzeptabel. - Und: Es wäre übrigens schön, wenn du auch eine Frage stellen würdest...

Comment: Servus und willkommen beim Stackexchange der deutschen Sprache. Du kannst eine [tour] der Seite nehmen. Es stellt sich mir die Frage, was in deiner Frage eigentlich die Frage ist – bedenke, dass wir einem Frage–Antwort-Schema folgen. Siehe auch [ask].

Comment: In Englisch: a run on sentence. In Deutsch: ganz normal! ;)

Comment: @Marakai: Ein Run-on Sentence ist ein Satzzeichenfehler, nämlich das Unterschlagen eines Semikolons bei der Aneinanderreihung mehrerer Hauptsätze. Diesen gibt es so im Deutschen nicht. Selbst wenn wir den Begriff weiter fassen und alle Aneinanderreihungen von Hauptsätzen als Run-on Sentence auffassen, ist dies keiner, da es nur einen Hauptsatz gibt.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Meh. Nehme den Kommentar zurück. Mir geht's heute ziemlich mies, scheiss erkältung. Brauche trotzdem den Schulmeisterton zu einem smiley-dekorierten comment nicht.

Comment: @Marakai: Ich sehe kein Tonproblem, nur eine sachliche Erklärung, was ein _run-on sentence_ tatsächlich ist und warum es sich hier nicht um einen solchen handelt. Das Ziel von SE-Sites ist es, (korrekte) Informationen zusammenzutragen; wenn du Korrekturen nicht verträgst, bist du hier vielleicht nicht am richtigen Platz.

Comment: @chirlu Warum die Annahme, dass ich nicht weiss, was ein ROS wirklich ist? Englisch ist inzwischen wahrscheinlich noch mehr "Muttersprache" als deutsch für mich. Wie mir deutsche Freunde und Familie nicht müde werden auf die Nase zu reiben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mit zwei kleinen Korrekturen wird der Satz zumindest richtig:

> Den Umstand, dass die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglied zwischen den Fachbereichen Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik und deren theoretischen Ansätze**n** und empirischen Methoden fungier**en**, finde ich höchst interessant und bewundernswert.

Aber er ist schwer zu lesen. Du könntest ihn so umformulieren:

> Ich finde es höchst interessant und bewundernswert, dass die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglied fungieren zwischen den Fachbereichen Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik sowie deren theoretischen Ansätzen und empirischen Methoden.

Aus dem eingeschobenen wird damit ein nachgestellter Nebensatz, und durch das Verschieben der langen Aufzählung in das Nachfeld ("Ausrahmung") wird auch der Nebensatz selbst etwas übersichtlicher. Lang ist der Satz dann aber immer noch. Falls es der Aufbau des Textes hergibt, würde ich versuchen, die Aufzählung vorab unterzubringen und mit einem Begriff zu belegen, so dass Du in Deinem Satz dann einfach darauf verweisen kannst.

Ob er angemessen ist, hängt sehr davon ab, an wen er sich richtet. In einem akademischen Kontext könnte er als normal empfunden werden. Einen Job bei der Bild-Zeitung bekommst Du damit eher nicht ;-)

Comment: Ich fands nicht schwer zu lesen, aber die Alternative noch leichter. :)

Comment: @Matthias Vielen Dank für deinen Verbesserungsvorschlag. Der ganze Satz findet in einem akademischen Kontext statt. Ich denke, dann kann ich ihn so lassen.

Answer (score 4):

Der Satz ist (bis auf einen kleinen Fehler: »Ansätze**n**« statt »Ansätze«) grammatisch korrekt, aber durch die vielen Aufzählungen und Einschübe etwas kompliziert und daher für viele Leser schwer verständlich. Außerdem enthält er eine Konstruktion, die sich unterschiedlich interpretieren lässt, was vor allem in Bezug auf die Wahl von Singular oder Plural bei bestimmten Worten divergierende Erwartungshaltungen verursachen kann. Das führt dann dazu, dass einige Leser Teile für falsch halten, obwohl sie sich bei geeigneter Interpretation als korrekt erweisen können.

---

### Analyse

Analysieren wir also den Satz, und zerlegen ihn in seine Bestandteile, in der Hoffnung, sie später in gefälligerer Reihenfolge wieder zu einem Satz mit derselben Aussage zusammenzufügen:

Urversion:

> **Den Umstand**, dass die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglied zwischen den Fachbereichen Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik und deren theoretischen Ansätzen und empirischen Methoden fungiert, **finde ich höchst interessant und bewundernswert**.

Das ist der Hauptsatz:

> Den Umstand finde ich höchst interessant und bewundernswert.

Du hast das Akkusativobjekt (den Umstand) an den Anfang, und das Subjekt (ich) hinter das Prädikat (finde) gesetzt. Das ist erlaubt, und guter Stil wenn du den Fokus auf *den Umstand*, und nicht auf *ich* legen möchtest. Trotzdem sei hier auch die Standard-Reihenfolge (Subjekt - Prädikat - Objekt) erwähnt:

> Ich finde den Umstand höchst interessant und bewundernswert.

Zum Zweck der weiteren Analyse ersetze ich diesen Satz durch einen einfacheren (mit einer ganz anderen Aussage, was aber nicht weiter stören soll), bei dem der Umstand am Ende des Satzes steht:

> Es gibt den Umstand.

Schauen wir weiter, wie der ganze Satz nun aussieht:

> ***Es gibt den Umstand,* dass die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglied** zwischen den Fachbereichen Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik und deren theoretischen Ansätzen und empirischen Methoden **fungiert.**

Wir betrachten nun den nicht kursiv dargestellten Teil des folgenden Satzes:

> *Es gibt den Umstand,* dass die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglied fungiert.

Dabei handelt es sich um einen Nebensatz, der von der Subjunktion »*dass*« eingeleitet wird. Da dieser Nebensatz eine Beifügung zu einem Bestandteil des Hauptsatzes (nämlich zum Umstand) ist, handelt es sich dabei um einen Attributsatz, was zwar semantisch wichtig ist, grammatisch aber keinen großen Unterscheid macht.

Man kann aus diesem Nebensatz einen Hauptsatz machen, indem man die einleitende Konjunktion weglässt, und das Prädikat von der letzten Stelle an die zweite rückt:

> Die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft fungiert als Bindeglied.

In diesem Satz gibt es eine Singular-Plural-Mehrdeutigkeit. Folgende Sätze wären eindeutiger:

> a) Die Medienkultur fungiert als Bindeglied.
>   b) Die Medienkultur und die Medienwirtschaft fungieren als Bindeglieder.
>   c) Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft fungieren als Bindeglieder.
>   d) Die Medienkultur oder Medienwirtschaft fungiert als Bindeglied.

a) Das Subjekt (*Die Medienkultur*) ist ein einzelner Begriff, der im Singular steht, daher muss auch das Prädikat im Singular stehen. Im Normalfall steht dann auch das Objekt im Singular, das muss aber nicht zwingend so sein (z.B. »[Ich bin zwei Tanks](https://c1.staticflickr.com/4/3043/2484646856_36d6161642_b.jpg)«).

b) Hier bildet eine Aufzählung (bestehend aus zwei Bestandteilen) das Subjekt, und weil mehrere Dinge im Subjekt enthalten sind, muss das Prädikat im Plural stehen. Für gewöhnlich steht dann auch das Objekt im Plural, was aber ebenfalls nicht zwingend ist (»Otto und Hilde sind ein Paar«).
Eine etwas ungewöhnliche Ausnahme von dieser Regel ist der »Singularis Materialis«, den uns vor 50 Jahren der Sänger und Musikproduzent Drafi Deutscher eingebrockt hat: Wenn die Aufzählung mehrere Materialien enthält, darf das Prädikat im Singular stehen. (Der Plural ist aber nach wie vor erlaubt und die bessere Wahl): »Marmor Stein und Eisen brechen« vs. »Marmor Stein und Eisen bricht«.

c) Wie b), jedoch haben beide Bestandteile der Aufzählung keinen Artikel (was man gelegentlich auch als Null-Artikel bezeichnet).

d) Hier steht im Subjekt keine Aufzählung, sondern es wurde ein Ding mit zwei alternativen Begriffen bezeichnet, wie z.B. auch in diesem Satz: »Der Samstag oder Sonnabend fungiert als Bindeglied zwischen Freitag und Sonntag.« Samstag und Sonnabend sind dasselbe, also ein Ding, und somit steht im Subjekt eben nur eine Sache, weswegen das Prädikat im Singular stehen muss.

Auffallend für b und c ist, dass beide Bestandteile der Aufzählung mit derselben Artikel-Art dastehen. In b ist es zweimal der bestimmte Artikel, in c zweimal der Null-Artikel (bzw. kein Artikel). Dem gegenüber steht in d, dass der eine Artikel für beide Wörter gilt. Natürlich ist auch das Bindewort (und - oder) ein anderes, und man kann auf semantischer Ebene hinterfragen, ob »Medienwirtschaft« tatsächlich als Synonym für »Medienkultur« durchgehen kann. Aber die Kombination

> {bestimmter Artikel} {Nomen} {Konjunktion} {Null-Artikel} {Nomen}

deutet eher auf eine alternative Bezeichnung und somit auf Singular als die anderen Kombinationen. Selbst dann, wenn das Bindewort »und« ein sehr deutliches Indiz für eine Aufzählung ist. Daher kann man in

> Die Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft fungiert als Bindeglied.

den Singular für »fungiert« mit etwas gutem Willen als richtig bewerten. Besser wäre es aber, Klarheit zu schaffen, indem man der Medienwirtschaft einen Artikel spendiert, und Prädikat und Objekt in den Plural setzt (sich also für b entscheidet):

> Die Medienkultur und die Medienwirtschaft fungieren als Bindeglieder.

Weiter in der Analyse:

> Die Medienkultur und die Medienwirtschaft fungieren als Bindeglieder **zwischen den Fachbereichen Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik und deren theoretischen Ansätzen und empirischen Methoden**.

Dieser Teil ist eine nähere Beschreibung der Bindeglieder, und sie besteht aus einer Aufzählung aus zwei Teilen, wobei beide Teile selbst wieder Aufzählungen sind.

Äußere Aufzählung:

1. die Fachbereiche Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik
2. deren theoretische Ansätze und empirischen Methoden

Die inneren Aufzählungen der beiden Teile wird jeder selbst erkennen.

---

### Synthese

Wenn man beim Leser voraussetzen kann, dass er mit komplizierten Sätzen gut umgehen kann, und wenn man selbst unter Beweis stellen will, dass man die deutsche Sprache auch auf einem gehobenen Niveau beherrscht, kann man die gewählte Grundstruktur beibehalten, und nur die notwendigsten Veränderungen vornehmen, um in der Frage »Singular oder Plural?« keine Schwächen zu zeigen, und um den kleinen Fehler bei den Ansätze**n** zu beheben. Das würde dann so aussehen (Änderungen gegenüber der Vorgabe sind fett hervorgehoben):

> Den Umstand, dass die Medienkultur und **die** Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglied**er** zwischen den Fachbereichen Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik und deren theoretischen Ansätze**n** und empirischen Methoden fungier**en**, finde ich höchst interessant und bewundernswert.

Will man diese Aussage aber jemandem klarmachen, der gerade dabei ist Deutsch als Fremdsprache zu lernen, oder der aus anderen Gründen eher mit einfachen Sätzen vertraut ist, würde ich Einschübe weitgehend vermeiden:

> Ich finde es höchst interessant und bewundernswert, dass die Medienkultur und die Medienwirtschaft als Bindeglieder fungieren, welche zwei Dinge miteinander verbinden, nämlich auf der einen Seite die Fachbereiche Kulturwissenschaft, Geschichtswissenschaft, Rechtswissenschaft, Wirtschaftswissenschaft und Informatik, und auf der anderen Seite die theoretischen Ansätze und empirischen Methoden dieser Fachbereiche.

---

Inhaltlich möchte ich aber gerne nachfragen, ob alles, was in diesem Satz ausgesagt wird, allgemeine Zustimmung findet. Dieser Satz unterstellt nämlich:

- Die aufgezählten Fachbereiche haben theoretischen Ansätze und sie haben empirische Methoden.
- Diese Fachbereiche und deren eigene Ansätze bzw. Methoden sind nicht notwendigerweise miteinander verbunden, können aber verbunden werden.
- Diese Verbindung wird durch Medienkultur und durch Medienwirtschaft hergestellt.

Ich glaube nämlich eher, dass Medienkultur und Medienwirtschaft die einzelnen Fachbereiche miteinander verbinden können, und dass sie vielleicht auch Ansätze und Methoden miteinander verbinden. Das wird im analysierten Satz aber nicht zum Ausdruck gebracht. Dass die Medienwirtschaft einen Fachbereich mit einer Methode verbindet, halte ich für eine gewagte Aussage.

Comment: Lange Weile oder was? Aber sehr schön. ;-)

Zur Semantik des Ganzen nur so viel: Medienkultur oder -wirtschaft sind Metaebenen, die alles behandeln oder verbinden können, von daher ist der Satz wohl eher inhaltslos, aber für ein Motivationsseminar vlt. hilfreich. *SCNR*